# How to get rows from other table in SQL with some condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:
`tbl_AliedMaster` and `tbl_PlantMaster`.

`tbl_AliedMaster` has structure like this:

```
Id  Empid       Name            Mobile          Email           Designation
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   UBM1001     John            1211567890      john@a.com          UBM
2   TSM1001     Root            1212121212      root@a.com          TSM
3   PI2         Billy           7862653222      billy@a.com         PI
4   PI6         YongLee         1452369872      lee@a.com           PI
```

`tbl_PlantMaster` have structure like this:

```
Plantid     plantcode   FSEID
--------------------------------
1           NS01        UBM1001
2           NS01        TSM1001
3           NS09        PI2
4           NS01        PI6
```

Here `FSEID` of `plantmaster` map to the `Empid` of `AliedMaster` table
I want to get Email of designation `UBM` and `TSM` when I select a `Empid` of his `plantcode`.
That is for `Empid` `PI6`, I want to get email of `John` and `Root` as they share same `plant code`.
Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT  Email
from tbl_AliedMaster
Where designation like '%UBM%'
  and Empid IN (SELECT FSE_Empid FROM tbl_PlantMaster WHERE FSE_Empid = 'PI6')
```

I know this is wrong and not giving me the desired result. I tried other queries too by matching those plant code but with the users, but failed.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: wait, when you select FSEID PI6, you should also get email of Lee isn't it since 3 of those record share the same plantcode (NS01)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get all empid follow plantcode

```
SELECT  Email
from tbl_AliedMaster
Where designation like '%UBM%'
  and Empid IN (SELECT FSE_Empid FROM tbl_PlantMaster WHERE plantcode = 'NS01')
```

OR

```
SELECT  Email
from tbl_AliedMaster
Where designation like '%UBM%'
  and Empid IN 
   (SELECT FSE_Empid FROM tbl_PlantMaster WHERE plantcode IN 
     ( SELECT plantcode  FROM tbl_PlantMaster WHERE FSE_Empid = 'PI6'))
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But I when I'll be fetching result I won't have plantcode. I'll only have  Empid of tbl_AliedMaster

Comment: try my second solution

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT  Email
from tbl_AliedMaster
Where 
 Empid IN ( select FSEID from tbl_PlantMaster where designation like '%UBM%' and plantcode in ( SELECT plantcode  FROM tbl_PlantMaster WHERE FSE_Empid = 'PI6'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tried this but I think this should work

```
select email.tbl_AliedMaster from tbl_AliedMaster,tbl_PlantMaster Where designation like '%M' and Id.tbl_AliedMaster=Plantid.tbl_PlantMaster Group by plantcode.tbl_PlantMaster Having count(*)<1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways.

**With a subquery**

```
 SELECT DISTINCT A.email
 FROM tbl_AliedMaster A
 WHERE A.Designation LIKE '%UBM%'
 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_PlantMaster B WHERE A.Empid=B.FSEID);
```

OR

**With a join**

```
 SELECT DISTINCT A.email
 FROM tbl_AliedMaster A INNER JOIN tbl_PlantMaster B ON A.Empid=B.FSEID
 WHERE A.Designation LIKE '%UBM%';
```